# How to return a mongoose document from a function using typescript

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose

I have two routes that do the same operation on a token to extract a user document from the database. After that, both perform different operations on that document. To improve the code, I am trying to put that same operation part in a function and call it in both routes. Something like -

```
    let user = await returnUser(req, res, token)
    user.verified = true;
    await user.save();
```

But the problem is I am using Typescript and I am getting type errors when doing something like user.save() or accessing the items in the document. Can anyone tell me how do I set up the types so that I can access the document returned from the function without getting type errors.

Edit: I am adding the code.
The function that will be returning a document -

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { Token } from "../util/token";
import { User } from "../models/user";

export const returnUser = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  token: string
) => {
  if (!token) return res.status(400).send({ error: "Token is not present" });

  let decoded = await Token.decode(token);

  if (decoded === false) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid Token" });
  }

  let email = decoded.email;
  let user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) return res.status(400).send({ error: "User not found" });
  if (user.createdAt.getTime() !== decoded.epoch)
    return res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid timestamp" });

  return user;
};
```

And the error -

[Message when hovering over the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KvON.png)

my UserDoc -

```
interface UserDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  email: string;
  username: string | null;
  verified: boolean;
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

Comment: please add more of your implementation so we can see what you're trying to improve

Comment: the exact error would be great

Comment: @AshwynHorton added the code.

Comment: @AutMai also added the error.

Comment: does it return you a real user-document? maybe add an example user doc

Comment: @AutMai it is supposed to return a user document fetched from the database

Comment: @41x3n yeah but i just meant you should check if it really does (it is supposed to but if it works ... nobody knows) - try `console.log(user)` afer "finding" it and maybe provide this output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the cause of the problem is that you are returning `response.send()`, which does not have type `UserDoc`, but as far as i could tell you're model is right. I cant see the code for your `Schema` but we will address it anyhow. So let us begin:

1. let us consider the `Schema` first,

```
// a schema definition does accept a generic reference when instantiating it.
// this also adds better typings with mongoose
export const UserDocSchema = new mongoose.Schema<UserDoc>({/* model */});
```

2. now let us look at the implementation provided. the error is caused by the returning response calls in the function, so will define an explicit return type on the function. making the function return this type will give the type errors where you are returning the `res.send()` calls...

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { Token } from "../util/token";
import { User } from "../models/user";

// so to stop the return errors we will instead of return send responses
// we will take advantage of the error handling situation which will fix
// the typing dilemma...
export const returnUser = async (token: string): Promise<UserDoc> => {
  if (!token) throw Error("Token is not present");

  let decoded = await Token.decode(token);
  if (decoded === false) {
    throw Error("Invalid Token");
  }

  let email = decoded.email;
  let user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) throw Error("User not found");
  if (user.createdAt.getTime() !== decoded.epoch)
    throw Error("Invalid timestamp");

  return user;
};
```

3. so now with the function the way it is, we will call your function like
   so based on the screenshot you provided...

```
router.post('user/verify', (request, response) => {
  const { token } = request.body;

  return returnUser(token)
  .then((user) => {
    // this way this function is guaranteed to return a user
    return response.status(200).send(user.toObject());
  })
  .catchError((error) => {
    return response.status(400).send({ error: error.message });
  });
});
```

UPDATE:

to import UserDoc you will have to export it here,

```
export interface UserDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  email: string;
  username: string | null;
  verified: boolean;
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

I haven't had the chance to test this but I think it should explain why your function call is making the typings error suggestions...Hope this works out

Comment: How do I import that UserDoc> Inside the user model file, I am exporting this only - const User = mongoose.model<UserDoc, UserModel>("User", userSchema);

export { User };

Do I export { User, UserDoc }

Comment: Oh i see that, just add ```export``` behind your interface definition in your problem statement

Comment: Hey man. Thank you for the detailed answer. It helped me a lot. I have now implemented the solution and it is working as I expected it to. I am attaching a link for the code. I followed what you showed though did not use throw Error as I have not set up an error handler yet. Thank you, man. https://pastebin.com/082ks3q8

Comment: Great, I checked the solution you have there. Quick tip, the implementation you have risks calling the ```send``` function twice which will cause a runtime error coz you can only respond once.

Comment: Should I use a return null option?

Comment: I think as long as you are aware of what might happen, you can decide...I'd say though, explore error handling. You could have an implementation with no ```if``` checks above.